# QWidget for showing text with small pictures (icons/emoticons)

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qwidget

Does such widget exist?

I can write my own widget based on `QLabel`s and layout similar to http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtwidgets-layouts-flowlayout-example.html, but then I can't select all text and copy (because this is just a set of labels).

Comment: Why do you think you cannot select text in QLabel?

Comment: Maybe I can, but I can't do it in multiple labels at one time.

Answer (score 4):

A QLabel's [text property](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qlabel.html#text-prop) can have rich text in it, and the [img tag is supported](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html) in rich text in Qt.

For example,

```
QLabel myLabel("<img src=\":/foo.png\"> Hello, World!");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `QTextEdit` in which when you enter some specific text, it changes to an image like a smiley or emoticon. You should react on `textChanged()` signal and use `QTextCursor` to modify the text replacing string with some HTML image tags:

```
QObject::connect(textEdit, SIGNAL(textChanged()), this, SLOT(changePixmap()),Qt::QueuedConnection) ;

void CSmsWidget::changePixmap()
{
     QRegExp reg(":\\)"); // you can improve regular expression
     QTextCursor cursor(textEdit->document()->find(reg));

     if (!cursor.isNull()) 
     {
         cursor.insertHtml("<img src=\":/images/happy_smilie.png\">");
     }
}
```