# Pasting emoji in QT QTextEdit

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface, qt4, qt5.3

I'm trying to paste emoji's in the QT QTextEdit box but it's not getting recognized and it's showing as ??? or [][]

I'm not talking about smiley, I'm talking about emoji.

How can I go about making sure that QT's QTextEdit accepts emoji and displays them correctly?

Thank you.

**Got it based on the helpful answer below:**

**SOLUTION:**

```
    QFontDatabase fontDB;
    fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/Resources/fonts/seguisym.ttf");

    QApplication::setFont(QFont(QStringLiteral("Segoe UI Symbol")));
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [QWidget for showing text with small pictures (icons/emoticons)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23463457/qwidget-for-showing-text-with-small-pictures-icons-emoticons)

Comment: Overriding this seems a way to go: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertFromMimeData

Comment: @Merlin069 I don't think that is a valid duplicate, pasting probably has its own issues, out of scope of that Q.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A considerable number of ***emoji*** characters are in the [Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode7.0.0/).
If you're, for example, developing with Qt 5.3 in Mac OS X 10.9, pasting ***emoji*** characters in text edits should work as it does when pasting any other character.

The reason why your application is showing `?`'s and/or `[]`'s is because the current font (perhaps the default system font) doesn't provide representations for ***emoji*** "characters".
You can find a proper font out there in the web. Check [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_font) for reference.

Then you can add the font to your Qt application

```
QFontDatabase fontDB;
fontDB.addApplicationFont(":/A Font Supporting Emoji.ttf");
```

and set it as the font for your application or only your `QTextEdit` if you prefer

```
setFont(QFont(QStringLiteral("A Font Supporting Emoji")));
```

With this your app should be able to display ***emoji***.

Answer (score 0):

The Qt documentation of QTextEdit::paste() says: `To change the behavior of this function, i.e. to modify what QTextEdit can paste and how it is being pasted, reimplement the virtual canInsertFromMimeData() and insertFromMimeData() functions.`

There you should be able to convert the pasted data e.g. to an HTML img element pointing to a file that is embedded into the application by ressource compiler (or to image file on disk).