# How can I use color emoji in Qt 5.7.0?

Tags: emoji, qt5.7

On Windows, with Qt 5.7.0.

I tried "Emoji One Color" font, like this:

```
QFontDatabase::addApplicationFont(":/Fonts/EmojiOneColor.ttf");

QFont font("EmojiOne Color");
ui.textEdit->setFont(font);
```

Copy "" from getemoji.com and paste them into QTextEdit widget,
it still displays the black/white Emoji.

How can I use color emoji in Qt 5.7.0 ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pasting emoji in QT QTextEdit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25727970/pasting-emoji-in-qt-qtextedit)

Comment: any solution to this, or is Qt 5.10 necessary?